# Why does my compiler not accept fork(), despite my inclusion of <unistd.h>?

Tags: c, windows, mingw, fork

Here's my code (created just to test fork()):

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

int main()
{   
    int pid;     
    pid=fork();

    if (pid==0) {
        printf("I am the child\n");
        printf("my pid=%d\n", getpid());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get following warnings:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'fork'
undefined reference to 'fork'
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Do you have your C library's headers installed? How are you invoking your compiler?

Comment: gcc test.c -pedantic -Wall -o test.exe

Comment: are you sure fork() is part of stdio.h? it isn't according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/. maybe there is a conflict with another header file you are including?

Comment: Apparently it's part of <unistd.h> 
How can it be conflicting with what I included?

Comment: @user1166935: There are no conflicts. The problem is your compiler options. Try without `-pedantic`, it should work then.

Comment: @moesef: The word "fork" does not appear on the page you linked to. (Also, it's not in the C standard, so I don't see why it'd be in <stdio.h>)

Comment: @NiklasB.: `undefined reference` means "link error" -- `-pedantic` isn't going to make any difference.

Comment: @Billy: `implicit declaration of function 'fork'` means that the compiler doesn't know about the function as well.

Comment: @NiklasB.: Yes, that's true. But unrelated to the point that `-pedantic` isn't making any difference here. (And this warning is turned on when `-pedantic` is not anyway... all functions *should* be prototyped, even in C89 (and such is required in C99, C++))

Comment: @user1166935: What operating system are you using?  Is it possible you have a bad `unistd.h` file for some reason?

Comment: Also it is better to use pid_t rather than int for the variable pid. pid_t is a typedef provided for storing pid.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`unistd.h` and `fork` are part of the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). They aren't available on windows (`text.exe` in your gcc command hints that's you're not on *nix).

It looks like you're using gcc as part of [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW), which does provide the `unistd.h` header but does not implement functions like `fork`. [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) *does* provide implementations of functions like `fork`.

However, since this is homework you should already have instructions on how to obtain a working environment.

Comment: The OP has `<unistd.h>` available; otherwise gcc would have reported a fatal error for the missing header file.

Comment: MinGW does not implement fork(), you could perhaps try Cygwin (or a real POSIX system) if you really need fork().  Or, you could try a similar windows function.

Comment: Although Cygwin does implement `fork()`, [it ain't pretty](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/highlights.html#ov-hi-process).

Comment: see also http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/CygwinDllRemappingFailure re cygwin `fork()`

Comment: "should already have instructions on how to obtain a working environment" -if only Universities were that good.

Answer (score 8):

You have got `#include <unistd.h>` which is where `fork()` is declared.

So, you probably need to tell the system to show the POSIX definitions before you include the system headers:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
```

You can use 700 if you think your system is mostly POSIX 2008 compliant, or even 500 for an older system.  Because `fork()` has been around forever, it will show up with any of those.

If you are compiling with `-std=c99 --pedantic`, then all the declarations for POSIX will be hidden unless you explicitly request them as shown.

You can also play with `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`, but using `_XOPEN_SOURCE` implies the correct corresponding `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` (and `_POSIX_SOURCE`, and so on).

Comment: with gcc and glibc, the feature test macro [isn't actually required](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) for `fork`. Including [unistd.h](http://linux.die.net/include/unistd.h) is enough. The standard does state that applications should define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` before including headers though.

Answer (score 6):

As you've already noted, fork() should be defined in unistd.h - at least according to the man pages that come with Ubuntu 11.10.  The minimal:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pid_t procID;

    procID = fork();
    return procID;
}
```

...builds with no warnings on 11.10.

Speaking of which, what UNIX/Linux distribution are you using?  For instance, I've found several non-remarkable functions that should be defined in Ubuntu 11.10's headers aren't.  Such as:

```
// string.h
char* strtok_r( char* str, const char* delim, char** saveptr);
char* strdup( const char* const qString);

// stdio.h
int fileno( FILE* stream);

// time.h
int nanosleep( const struct timespec* req, struct timespec* rem);

// unistd.h
int getopt( int argc, char* const argv[], const char* optstring);
extern int opterr;
int usleep( unsigned int usec);
```

As long as they're defined in your C library it won't be a huge problem.  Just define your own prototypes in a compatibility header and report the standard header problems to whoever maintains your OS distribution.

Comment: `fork` is available on far more than "GNU/Linux" systems -- it's available anywhere POSIX is supported, which includes GNU/Hurd, Unix, BSD, etc. (And for the record, I believe the OP is on Windows given his comments)

Comment: (Oh, forgot Solaris and MacOSX, it's available there too)

Comment: Actually, I said "UNIX/Linux", but yes, fork() is a POSIX feature.

Just because your host OS provides unistd.h, doesn't mean it supports POSIX features (which actually is the main point of unistd.h [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unistd.h)).

That link provides a clue.  Maybe the OP needs to install Cygwin to provide some POSIX/Windows bridge.  Or just use a different host OS.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to do the following instead:

```
pid_t pid = fork();
```

To learn more about Linux API, go to [this online manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), or even go into your terminal right now and type,

```
man fork
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Just run the program in Linux virtual machine, mine worked there.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35442394)

Answer (score -1):

Run it in Linux system or wsl. I solved it in the way, too.