# undefined reference to function fork and getppid

Tags: c

The error I am getting on compiling the following code is
undefined reference to 'fork'
undefined reference to 'getppid'
error: ld returned 1 exit status

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    int pid;
    pid=fork();    //creates child process and stores the return value 
    if(pid>0)
        printf("parent process id:%d",getpid());    //prints the process id
    else if(pid==0)
        printf("Child process id:%d parent id:%d Parent process id:%d",getpid(),getppid());    //prints the process and parent id
    else
        printf("Error");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow, please read community guidelines to posting questions with correct tags.

Comment: Also your program snippet has no function definition for fork() or getpid() hence the undefined error.

Comment: @Saleem Ahmed Both `fork()` and `getpid()` as well as `getppid()` are defined in the header unistd.h, which is included in the code example above.

Comment: @Shagun Ramola What compiler are you using? Your example compiles without errors for me on GCC 4.9 on Debian Linux.

Comment: It is compiler configuration problem. Check the linked libraries.

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9612414/8549610 .